# G-cloud sdk --> problems about firebase projects and permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm developing a backend microservice app with node.js along with `@google-cloud/firestore` and i'm trying to access my firebase project locally with gcloud-sdk. I've run gcloud init so i can log in and chose the project i need to connect to in order to access the db.

The problem is that, i keep getting **7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions** when i try to make any type of interaction with the db even though i already have all permissions in the project. At the beginning i thought that maybe i was having that problem because i was using a different account that did not have permissions to access these projects, but that didn't make sense because i do not see that account in my list of accounts in the sdk

[image]

But, when i gave permissions to the other account that i thought maybe logged in in my sdk, i could access the db, so it was weird, it is like it's stuck with the other account that maybe i added when i first install the sdk.

So, i've tried everything to correct this, i've deleted all accounts from my gcloud sdk, i've deleted the list of configurations, i've uninstalled (twice) the sdk and installed it again (since people that i work with told me that they did this and worked for them, since they had same issue), i've run `g cloud init` to log in again and all that stuff, and still, when i try to connect to my firebase db, it still says that i still do not have permissions, it's like the account that i'm logging in is not the one that is being saved/used to access my project.

What can i do to make this work ?

**EDIT #1 -> How i'm connecting to firebase and sdk commands to connect to the project**

Connecting to my project on firestore

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Firestore } from '@google-cloud/firestore';
import { GCP_PROJECT } from '@util';

export const firestore = new Firestore({ projectId: GCP_PROJECT });
```

Commands to connect to my project by sdk

```
-> gcloud init
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Settings from your current configuration [coordinadora-work] are:
core:
  account: diego.cifuentes@coordinadora.com
  disable_usage_reporting: 'True'
  project: cm-reparto-dev

Pick configuration to use:
 [1] Re-initialize this configuration [coordinadora-work] with new settings 
 [2] Create a new configuration
Please enter your numeric choice:  1

Your current configuration has been set to: [coordinadora-work]

You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:
  gcloud init --skip-diagnostics

Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.                                                                                                                                      
Reachability Check passed.
Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).

Choose the account you would like to use to perform operations for this configuration:
 [1] diego.cifuentes@coordinadora.com
 [2] Log in with a new account
-> Please enter your numeric choice:  1

You are logged in as: [...my account that is having problems...].


Pick cloud project to use: 
...

-> Please enter numeric choice or text value (must exactly match list item):  21

Your current project has been set to: [...project that i'm having problems with...].

-> Do you want to configure a default Compute Region and Zone? (Y/n)?  n

Your Google Cloud SDK is configured and ready to use!
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include how you connect on Firestore Database? Also, provide the database rule.

Comment: Please add your code from the imports to where you are using them. It'll be best to see how you are initializing the SDK.

Comment: I've added more details as you told me, plase let me know if it's enough, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The `Google Cloud Client libraries` use the `Application Default Credentials`, not the current credentials setup using `gcloud auth login`.

To setup your `Application Default Credentials` for local development, simple execute `gcloud auth application-default login`. This will open a browser window and allow you to select the account to use as default credentials.

Another method is setting the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to a service account key file.

Read more here : https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials

When running in GCP, your credentials will get picked up from the environment, i.e. the service account your Cloud Function is running with.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/client-libraries